# Combining multiple for loops in Python

Tags: python

Let's say, we have and list of objects in variable called "articles", each object has a member "tags" (which is simple list).

Expected output: all tags in all articles, joined in a single list.

In multiple lines, solution would be:

```
arr = []
for article in articles:
    for tag in article.tags:
       arr.append(tag)
```

Now, how can we write this in single line instead of 4?

This syntax is invalid:

```
arr = [tag for tag in article.tags for article in articles]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547155/can-someone-explain-this-program-to-me/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's invalid because `article` doesn't exist by the time the first loop is parsed.

```
arr = [tag for article in articles for tag in article.tags]
```

Comment: Tied for best answer and answered the longest time ago. Pick this one, OP.

Answer (score 5):

You are actually looping in the order that you don't want to order:

what you want is:

```
result = [ tag for article in articles for tag in article.tags ]
```

To translate what you were doing in your example would be:

```
for tag in article.tags:
    for article in articles:
       #code
```

which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
arr = [tag for tag in (a.tags for a in articles)]
```

Comment: I think a generator expression (`()` instead of `[]`) for the inner loop would be better.

Comment: in this case, arr output will be: `[[a1_tag1, a1_tag2], [a2_tag1, a2_tag2]]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import itertools
it = itertools.chain.from_iterable(article.tags for article in articles)
l  = list(it) # if you really need a list and not an iterator
```

Comment: Cool! Wouldn't `(article.tags for article in articles)` i.e. generator be even better?

Answer (score 2):

If you want *unique* tags, you might be better served by

```
import operator
tags = reduce(operator.__or__, (set(article.tags) for article in articles), set())
```

**Edit:**

- For Python 3, you would need to

  ```
  from functools import reduce
  ```
- The initializer `set()` is returned if the sequence is empty, rather than throwing an error.

Comment: This one is very elegant solution. There were no uniqueness requirement - I have planned to convert the list to set later, but your code is one step ahead ;) Few possible problems - reduce is removed from Python 3 standard library (not a big deal, but it means something) and "if the sequence is empty, an exception is raised".

Answer (score 2):

This is already answered multiple times, but it can be helpful to break lines and indent:

```
arr = [tag 
       for article in articles
           for tag in article.tags]
```

This has the advantage of

1. Making it more readable if you needed to do some kind of projection on tag (like getting `(tag.name, tag.description, tag.count)` or some other tuple or transformation of a tag)
2. Making the syntax for nested generator expressions more readable to a beginner
3. Making complex nested generator expressions more readable