# Can someone explain this program to me?

Tags: python

What does the following expression produce as a value:

```
[(x, x*y) for x in range(2) for y in range(2)]
```

1. `[(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]`
2. `[0, 1, 2]`
3. `[(0,0), (1,0), (0,0), (1,1)]`
4. `[(0,0), (0,0), (1,0), (1,1)]`
5. None of the above

The answer is *4*, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544549/combining-multiple-for-loops-in-python  Popular topic today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming python 2.

`range(2)` returns the list `[0, 1]`

```
[(x, x*y) for x in [0, 1] for y in [0,1]]
```

Thus x and y will be all combinations of the lists `[0, 1]` and `[0, 1]`

```
[(x, x*y) for (x, y) in [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]]

x    y    x*y    (x, x*y)
0    0    0      (0, 0)
0    1    0      (0, 0)
1    0    0      (1, 0)
1    1    1      (1, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  It looks like the F.O.I.L method to me.

Answer (score 2):

read as:

```
for x in range(2): # 0,1
  for y in range(2): # 0,1
     (x, x*y)
```

Comment: I'm still not understanding.  
I think I get why the first one would be (0,0)
 
It's because (x, x*y) = (0, (0*1 = 0) = (0,0)
 
But what is happening after that?

Comment: @Sim then you get `(0, 0*1), (1, 1*0), (1, 1*1)`

Answer (score 1):

Read this as

```
list = [];
for x in range(2):
  for y in range(2):
    list.append((x, x*y))
```

Basically it will iterate 4 times with the following X,Y values

```
X=0, Y=0
X=0, Y=1
X=1, Y=0
X=1, Y=1
```

Zero times anything will always be zero, so you get your 4 arrays

```
First Index = 0, 0*0
Second Index = 0, 0*1
Third Index = 1, 1*0
Fourth Index = 1, 1*1
```

Answer (score 1):

Nested list comprehensions work in the same way as if you had written for loops like that.

So your example list comprehension works like this generator function:

```
def example():
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(2):
            yield (x, x*y)
```

Comment: they are square brackets, what is getting created is a complete list with all values not a generator function.

Comment: @sateesh: Yes, it's true.  If you call `list(example())`, the result will be option D from the question.

Comment: as I see you are suggesting your geneartor function as analogus to the code OP posted, which I think is not correct. As other answers indicated the analogus code is : mylist.append((x,x*y)) (the yield statement you are using is misleading)

Comment: @sateesh: That will have the same effect as `list(example())`.  They are just two different ways of doing the same thing.  Info on generator functions is at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators